# Use inside Python code that has been written on IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

i wrote on IronPython code, compile it into dll
now i try it use into python by ctypes.

```
# mydll.py code on ironpython
class Pa(object):
    def convert(self):
        # some code that use C# dll

# compile it by this way
# ipy.exe Tools\Scripts\pyc.py myDll.py /out:myDll /target:dll /standalone

# python interpreter
# i try use it
c = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\myDll.dll")
c.Pa()
# AttributeError: function 'Pa' not found
```

By what way i can use inside python code that has been written on IronPython.
is it possible convert to python bite code?
maybe wrote a extension on CPython ?

Comment: i can't imagine how solve it. i go through simplest way by create com object.